# Node.js : New session at every refresh/access

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, node.js, session

I'm trying to implement a session system on my Node.js app.

I'm using express4, express-session and express-mysql-session.

I want to store a session for each visitor when he visits the site for the first time. I wrote this piece of code:

```
var sessionStoreCo = mysqllib.createMySQLConnection(mysql, Conf);

var sessionStore = new MySQLSessionStr({}, sessionStoreCo);
app.use(session({
    cookieName: 'session',
    resave: true,
    secret: Conf.GetSessionSecretString(),
    cookie: {maxAge: 5000000000, secure: true},
    store: sessionStore
}))
```

The thing is, every time I refresh the page, a new session is inserted in my MySQL database.

I can't get the previous one, the one that just have been created.

Did I miss something ? An option ? I looked at the express-session npm doc but didn't find something worth it.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I founded the reason why.

In the doc, it's mention that the secure statement (in the cookie declaration) is related to an SSL access to the website.

In fact, if the secure is on true, the cookie and cookie informations will be used only if the made request is an SSL request.

It was not my case. I removed it, and now it's working.

Hope it helps!